# How to set two Codeigniter module sites in docker?

Tags: apache, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to migrate two sites built on a Codeigniter framework to a docker container.

To exemplify, I call the two applications site1 and site2. The path of the two sites in docker is:

`/var/www/html/application/modules/site1`

`/var/www/html/application/modules/site2`

Initially the **sites.conf** file in apache2 looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      
        ServerName 172.22.0.3 #IP container

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I want to perform an Nginx proxy redirect for both site1 and site2. Here's a simplified setup that I want to repeat for site2:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    server_name         site1.domain.com;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    include /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-errors-ptbr/nginx-errors.conf;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/mykey_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mykey.key;


    # logging
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/site1.access.log;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/site1.error.log warn;

    # reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://IP_HOST_DOCKER:8085/site1;
    }

}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name site1.domain.com;
    return      301 https://site1.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

How could I change the settings presented to access both sites?

Comment: What does this actually have to do with CodeIgniter?

Comment: @James I had put Codeigniter, because I didn't know if I would need to change something in the code to do what I want.